# Exception raise in Python 3.3

Tags: python

I have this example in book, but it does not work in my python 3.3

```
x = 'item found'

def search():
    raise x or return

try:
    search()
except x:
    print('exception')
else:
    print('no exception')
```

Could any one tell me why?

Comment: What book would that be? That's *not* valid Python.

Comment: I think you misread the book - it is saying _"put either `raise x` or `return` here, and see what happens when you run the code"_.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: `return` is a statement, not an expression. Statements have to appear on their own line. `raise` is a statement too, it expects it's expression to evaluate to an exception to raise, but neither `x` nor the `return` statement fulfills that.

As it stands, the line is complete nonsense. It is not valid Python.

What happens instead, is that the Python parser will flag this code as invalid and raise a `SyntaxError` exception *for the whole file*. No code contained in the file will actually be run:

```
  File "demo.py", line 4
    raise x or return
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```